# Formulário Dinâmico mostrando valor que não era pra mostrar

Tags: javascript, html

Fala galera, beleza ?
Quando eu crio um formulário dinâmico, ele tem como padrão no select, um Value vazio no option, que está definido como Value="N/A". Quando eu adiciono por exemplo, dois formulários dinâmicos para preencher, na hora de mostrar na o conteúdo ele mostra um que não foi requisitado, como N/A.

Na imagem, eu preenchi somente dois formulários dinâmicos de Interrupção, o Indisponibilidade de equipamentos e a Área de teste (eu coloquei o Início e Término como N/A mesmo). Porém ele adicionou sozinho na hora de exibir as interrupções uma chamada N/A, como na primeira imagem.

[image: O que mostra na tela]

Aqui é o formulário:
[image: Formulário]

Aqui estão os códigos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //group add limit
    var maxGroup = 10;
    
    //add more fields group
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
     if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
     }else{
      alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
     }
    });
    
    //remove fields group
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
     $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-heading"><b>Interrupções</b></div>
<div class="intcont">
 <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
  <div class="input-group">
   <select required="" class="form-control" id="interrupcao" name="interrupcao[]">
    <option value="N/A">Motivo</option>
    <option value="Indisponibilidade de equipamentos">Indisponibilidade de equipamentos</option>
    <option value="Indisponibilidade de Área de teste">Indisponibilidade de Área de teste</option>
    <option value="Outros (Descrever em Comentários)">Outros (Descrever em Comentários)</option>
   </select>
   <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="inicioint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Início"/>
   <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="terminoint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Término"/>
   <div class="input-group-addon"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Cópia do formulário pra gerar em baixo -->
 <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
  <div class="input-group">
   <select required="" class="form-control" id="interrupcao" name="interrupcao[]">
    <option value="N/A">Motivo</option>
    <option value="Indisponibilidade de equipamentos">Indisponibilidade de equipamentos</option>
    <option value="Indisponibilidade de Área de teste">Indisponibilidade de Área de teste</option>
    <option value="Outros (Descrever em Comentários)">Outros (Descrever em Comentários)</option>
   </select>
   <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="inicioint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Início"/>
   <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="terminoint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Término"/>
   <div class="input-group-addon"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button class="addMore">add</button>
```

E aqui é o código que irá mostrar em um PDF as interrupções:

```
  $html .= "<table>";
  $html .= "<tr>";
  $html .= "<th>INTERRUPÇÕES</th>";
  $html .= "<th>Início</th>";
  $html .= "<th>Término</th>";
  $html .= "</tr>";

  for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['interrupcao']); $i++) {

   $html .="<tr>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['interrupcao'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['inicioint'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['terminoint'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .= "</tr>";

  }
  $html .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Não consigo visualizar esse suposto erro

Comment: Sua pergunta me parece meio incompleta. Não mostra como chegar nessa tela do print que você postou na pergunta, e o código que postou não mostra erro algum.

Comment: Na hora de mostrar os valores do formulário, ele mostra esse N/A, como na imagem, sendo que não cadastrei um formulário com esse valor.

Comment: Alem da biblioteca jquery quais outras vc está usando, e o CSS? No meu servidor está diferente  http://kithomepage.com/sos/valor-na.htm

Comment: E como faz pra chegar a primeira imagem? qual é o código? Com o que vc postou não dá para fazer teste.

Comment: Editado, coloquei um trecho que exibe as interrupções adicionadas no formulário, porém ta adicionando esse N/A na hora de exibir =p

Comment: No código que você colocou de exemplo o erro não ocorre